# How to bypass a theme editor block?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I have downloaded a theme but would like to edit the PHP files, but there is a theme editor block. I can't access it by typing the theme editor into the url, I just wondered if there is a way of getting around it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is highly discouraged to edit themes like that, because any changes made that way will be deleted upon update. The recommended way is to create a child theme and edit your PHP CSS and HTML there.

> By using a child theme you will ensure that your modifications are
>   preserved.
>       Using a child theme can speed up development time.
>       Using a child theme is a great way to learn about WordPress theme development.

all the documentation to create a child theme is here [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to open functions.php for that theme outside of wp-admin. Like in a text editor or ide and upload it back to your themes folder.